# How to investigate RAM corruption in microcontroller?

Tags: embedded, stm32, microcontroller, ram, data-corruption

I have detected a Data corruption in RAM in one of STM32 based device.

The issue is very rare and
not reproducible. In one device, I have seen only single bit corruption. But it causes a lot of damage. From the behavior of other corrupted devices, I understand similar but not the same data corruption occured in the same region.

The corrupted value belongs to a static global array, which isn't modified in run time. From the Map file, I can see the array is placed in RAM base address.

I want to find out root cause of this corruption. What might be the most efficient way to go for this?

Project is developed using IAR EW for ARM and I am using ST-Link V2 Debugger.

Comment: "The issue is very rare and not reproducible" — that's the worst kind and you may never find a cause for this. A single-bit corruption, especially, can be caused by software or hardware issues. In the latter case, it can be a defect in the chip, a radioactive atom disintegrating nearby, cosmic rays remnant, an electromagnetic wave... Just be aware of that

Comment: Because you can never be sure that a RAM holds its content all the time, safety-related software needs to implement safety measures against corruption. If you took the seriously expected measures against corruption in the first place (clean supply, operation within specified limits, protection against radiation, you name it), you just cannot do anything against the very small probability left over and you need to consider corruption.

Comment: If you can reproduce it frequently then it's likely caused by a bug. In that case you would hook up a debugger with trace and set a write breakpoint on the cell. When a value gets written there, you view the trace to see who's the culprit.

Comment: The simplest thing to do is to place a Data Watchpoint (data breakpoint) on as much of the data in question as possible, check your toolchain for the size of Data Watchpoint, or mask on the address. A more complex method would involve MPU.

Comment: In case it's caused by hardware or cosmic rays, well... here's a check list of things you can do: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892379/584518

Comment: Is it possible you've got a software bug writing to the bit-banding memory region that is mapped to your array?   Does it happen on multiple devices? Is it the same place all the time?

Comment: It's not clear from the question, but could this array be stored in flash instead of RAM? You said "a static global array, which isn't modified in run time".

Comment: do you have your flash wait states set correctly for the clock speed and power?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I have stated in the question- "From the Map file, I can see the array is placed in RAM base address."

Comment: @old_timer, I have to check that. Can you explain a bit about how it may affect the RAM data?  The data that gets corrupted is loaded in the RAM at startup and never modified afterward.

Comment: I am asking why is it stored in RAM? If it never changes, it should probably be stored in flash. Make it `const`.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Yes, That should have been done. I will do that, that might as well fix this particular issue. However, I am trying to find out the root cause to protect any other RAM corruption issue in the future.

Comment: just a random thought: if your device has MPU, you can control RAM access at various moments of program execution. I would consider trying to lock various regions of RAM and see when illegal access exception happens. You can extract some useful data about where and how the error happened in the exception handler. It's not a silver bullet, there is no guarantee that you find it, but worth a shot.

Comment: @old_timer I have checked the Flash wait states configuration. The Flash wait state is sometimes set to 1 when 0 is required. but It is always 1 when 1 is required. It is an STM32L152RC MCU, which has two flash states. Can it cause an issue like this?

Comment: well I think it was asked maybe not, no code runs from flash only from ram?  anything in flash that has a marginal wait state can get corrupted causing any number of kinds of errors, now saying that the problems will appear random.  and if you go from one board to another it should change how it behaves as well (if it is a timing issue).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate your data and scatter verifying code like `assert(0==memcmp(&Data, &Copy, sizeof(Data)));` on your code. This is a low-level approach which takes a lot of time but may help to narrow the spot where the memory corruption takes place. Seriously, I localized a memory  corruption by using ugly code like `assert(*(int*)0x123==456);`.

Comment: In this approach, I will be able to narrow down the issue, If I can reproduce the issue, right? However, I am not able to reproduce the issue yet. Will this help my cause?

Comment: If you can record and retrive the failures of such `assert()`s in some way that should bring you forward. I am a great fan of `assert`, because you can place endless mines in your program which 'detonate' if your program begins to derail. The more, the better. In the final software those possibly performance-eating code is not present anymore. And yes, my `assert`s fired quite a few times because I malformed their condition and nothing was wrong with the main code.

Answer (score 0):

If MPU is available. Set the table zone as readonly after setup, handle busfault and generate and save the coredump for analisys.

Answer (score -1):

> static global array, which isn't modified in run time.

Place it in FLASH - it would not be modified

Comment: Beside being a generally good idea, this does not answer the question. :-(